# Get time of page loading start in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http, date, header, request

In JavaScript it is possible to wait for `onLoad` which may be used to specify the time of page loading completion.

Every HTTP response is sent along with `Date:` header which contains the time server sent a response.

Is there a way in JavaScript to get the time of page started loading?
Something similar to response `Date:` header.

It would be useful for cases when JavaScript is injected into page after some delay.

Comment: The server can write the time into the response in a number of ways: JavaScript code, HTML attribute values, etc.

Comment: Are you looking for "server" date?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`new Date(performance.timing.connectStart)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Navigation_timing) in chrome, firefox, IE9, etc ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_performance))

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xNUTB/)

```js
console.log(new Date(performance.timing.connectStart));
```

Comment: As a side bonus I learned that: *The window.performance.navigation object stores two attributes that can be used to know if a page load is triggered by a redirect, back/forward button or normal URL load.*

Answer (score 1):

Try storing a value from `var d= new Date(); var requested = d.getTime();` and execute it when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var loadDate;
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadDate=new Date();">
    <button onclick="alert(loadDate);">show load Date</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update 2023

As `performance.timing.connectStart` is deprecated, I recommend:

```js
window.performance?.timeOrigin
```

Here is my code to get something bullet-proof:

```js
    const sessionStartDateTime = window.performance?.timeOrigin ?? window.performance?.timing?.connectStart ?? Date.now();
```

Sources:

- [window.performance.timing deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73067785/window-performance-timing-deprecated)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming

Hope ir helps :)

Answer (score -1):

I would just pass a timestamp from the server-side script to the browser via a cookie or inline JS. E.g. in PHP:

```
<script>
var timestamp = new Date(<?php echo time(); ?>);
</script>
```